# Making Strip Map Polygons Flush?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, strip-map

When I create a strip map of a line the polygons overlap slightly even if I choose a 0% overlap. How Can I make the strip map completely flush without manually going through each frame and clipping them?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, unless your line is straight, or you are Ok to be part of it outside polygons

Comment: Not sure I follow what you are doing really, but maybe you can do something with either Data Frame Properties>Data Frame>Clip Options or Advanced Drawing Options>Layer Masking?

Comment: I was able to use topology to assist in finding the areas that overlap but I can't merge multiple overlapping areas, only one at a time.

Comment: Intersect your polygons with themselves (run intersect with only the one layer). Use the output to erase the original layer then merge the intersect output with the erased dataset. There will likely be some field you can dissolve on or you could try running Eliminate at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First do a self intersection (with only one layer in intersect).  Then erase the sliver polygons from the original frames.  Next dissolve the slivers with no input or statistical fields.  Do a one-to-one spatial join with the original slivers on the dissolved slivers with a field mapping of minimum page number to the output.  Merge the final sliver polygons with the pages that have the slivers erased.  Then dissolve the merged layer based on the page number.